# longformer-base-4096 (pytorch transformers) RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs

Tags: python

I am trying to fine-tune longformer with a custom dataset. I created a basic example with the documentation from hugging-face transformers. I receive the mentioned error. "
RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs "

```
train_data = load_dataset('csv', data_files='C:/Users/user/Desktop/result/train.csv')

test_data = load_dataset('csv', data_files='C:/Users/user/Desktop/result/test.csv')
model = LongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096',
                                                   gradient_checkpointing=False,
                                                       attention_window = 512,
                                                       num_labels=2)


tokenizer = LongformerTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096', max_length = 1024)

def tokenization(batched_text):
   return tokenizer(batched_text['msg'], padding = 'max_length', truncation=True, max_length = 1024)


train_data = train_data['train'].map(tokenization, batched = True, batch_size = len(train_data))


test_data = test_data['train'].map(tokenization, batched = True, batch_size = len(test_data))

train_data.set_format('torch', columns=['input_ids', 'attention_mask','bull'])

test_data.set_format('torch', columns=['input_ids', 'attention_mask','bull'])


# define the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir = 'Z:/crypto/aa/',
    num_train_epochs = 2,
    per_device_train_batch_size = 1,
    gradient_accumulation_steps = 16,    
    per_device_eval_batch_size= 16,
    evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
    disable_tqdm = False, 
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    warmup_steps=200,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_steps = 4,
#fp16 = True,
    logging_dir='Z:/crypto/aa//logs',
    dataloader_num_workers = 0,
    run_name = 'longformer-classification-updated- 
    rtx3090_paper_replication_2_warm'
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=test_data
)
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
device

trainer.train()
```